# How to get ellipsis in second line that is crossbrowser compatible [React]

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx, ellipsis

[Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3jJR.png)

I need to get like this. Clip is only working in chrome. I need this for a react project. Using css only would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one solution this way.

Something like this.

```
/* styles for '...' */ 
.block-with-text {
  /* hide text if it more than N lines  */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* for set '...' in absolute position */
  position: relative; 
  /* use this value to count block height */
  line-height: 1.2em;
  /* max-height = line-height (1.2) * lines max number (3) */
  max-height: 3.6em; 
  /* fix problem when last visible word doesn't adjoin right side  */
  text-align: justify;  
  /* place for '...' */
  margin-right: -1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
/* create the ... */
.block-with-text:before {
  /* points in the end */
  content: '...';
  /* absolute position */
  position: absolute;
  /* set position to right bottom corner of block */
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
/* hide ... if we have text, which is less than or equal to max lines */
.block-with-text:after {
  /* points in the end */
  content: '';
  /* absolute position */
  position: absolute;
  /* set position to right bottom corner of text */
  right: 0;
  /* set width and height */
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  /* bg color = bg color under block */
  background: white;
}
```

Ref. link - http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Trunk8](http://jrvis.com/trunk8/) plugin(jQuery) to achieve this effect. Where it has a browser compatibility and also responsive too.